# how to integrate Here maps to windows phone mobile app?

Tags: here-api

I want to create sample app for here maps in windows mobile.Please help me for this.

how to integrate here maps to my application?

Answer (score 0):

if it is really windows mobile that you are working with, then I would say that there is no native offering available for the platform. You could of course try using the javascript API on any web environment you could utilize with the platform.

For more information for the javascript offering you could visit [developer.here.com](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis)

Then if you would be targeting newer devices, such as devices having Windows Phone 8, then there would be native API which is using HERE maps, thus with that platform you could simply use it directly.